# 1 of my page doesn't apply my new setting (Wordpress/elementor pro)

Tags: wordpress, elementor

Hello i do some adjustment on my Navbar and add button "add to cart" on product menu, but  ONLY 1 of my 5 different categorie get the older version.

i try to disable "WPOptimize", regenerate css ,put the css file external or internal. None work .
Please help me , 2days i try to fix it .

Comment: Have tried to check page layout setting of particular page? https://elementor.com/help/using-elementors-full-width-page-template/